# Defining a function through a pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have the following code:

```
typedef void (*func_type)(int a, int b);
func_type func;

int main()
{
   func = (func_type)GetProcAddress(NULL, "func");
}
```

This code works fine, but I would like to change `func_type func;` to `void func(int a, int b);` (because code completion shows "func_type" instead of "func" when typing the parameters).
But when I try to change this, the compiler tells me that in the main function "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". I tried to look online but did not find an answer to my problem.
Code becomes this:

```
typedef void (*func_type)(int a, int b);
void func(int a, int b);

int main()
{
   func = (func_type)GetProcAddress(NULL, "func");
}
```

Comment: You are not defining any function here. You are defining function **_pointer_**, which points to other, already defined, function.

Comment: Please, post also the code in which _"you try to change it"_.

Comment: Nothing besides sanity is stopping you from using `void (*func)(int,int);` and in `main`, do `func = (void (*)(int,int))GetProcAddress(NULL, "func");` . You'll quickly realize how much handier it is to utilize one of only two truly valid reasons for pointer-type-hiding in a type alias as your original code shows (the other being blackbox "handle" APIs).

Comment: It may a bit easier to grasp if `typedef void func_type(int,int);` was used. Then you could define `func` as `func_type *func`. Because `func` is *a pointer* to a function. The cast would be ` ... = (func*)GetProcAddress(...)`.

Comment: Your request is not possible - `GetProcAddress` returns a pointer, and that is the only way to store a function address.  If you want a function name to bind at compile-time to some library function that is called *early binding* and is not done via a runtime call `GetProcAddress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in C behave similar to arrays. They both decay to pointers. Whenever function name is used it automatically decays to *a pointer* to this function. The exceptions are `&` and `sizeof` operators. Operator `sizeof` does not accept a function as operand. That is why `foo` and `&foo` are equivalent.

Functions itself are non-modifiable by *design*. Any attempt of modifying it i.e. by `memcpy`-ing to a function pointer is *undefined behaviour*.

Surprisingly, function call operator `()` *does not* take a function as operand but *a pointer to a function*.

Therefore, a function call

```
foo(1);
```

is actually

```
(&foo)(1);
```

Because `foo` decays to `&foo` before evaluation of the function call.

That is why one can interchangeably use functions and function pointer in function call operands.

```
void foo(int) { ... }
void (*bar)(int);

foo(1); // foo decays to &foo which is a function pointer
bar(2); // bar is already a function pointer
```

To solve the original problem I suggest keeping `func` be a function pointer, that initially points to some dedicated function but it can be overwritten later on:

```
typedef void func_type(int,int);

void default_func(int a, int b) { ... }

funt_type* func = default_func; // decays to &default_func !

int main()
{
   func(1,2); // calls default_func
   func = (func_type*)GetProcAddress(NULL, "func");
   func(3,4); // calls func from dll/so
}
```

I've decided to use function types (not function pointer types) what is a bit un-orthodox. IMO, it make syntax more visually pleasing, and it is easier to parse by a human. Moreover, it is explicit about what is a pointer what is not.

Comment: Functions are not objects. An object in C is a “region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values” (C 2018 3.15 1). C has different rules for objects and functions, including different rules about conversions of pointers to objects to pointers to different object types (6.3.2.3 7) and conversions of pointers to functions to pointers to different function types (6.3.2.3 8).

Comment: You might want to clarify or delete "The exceptions is `&`". I think I know what you want to say there, but not sure.

Comment: Automatic conversion a function designator to a pointer has two exceptions, when it is the operand of `sizeof` and when it is the operand of unary `&`. Although `sizeof` is not defined for functions, the except is important because otherwise `sizeof func` would be converted to `sizeof &func`, and then `sizeof` would give the size of the pointer to the function.

Comment: Functions are not lvalues (C 2018 6.3.2.1 1: “An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potential designates an object…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil, fixed, thanks for pointing that function are not objects. Frankly, I've always thought that functions are just a "special" type of objects. If not objects then not l-values as well.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef void (*func_type)(int a, int b);` declares `func_type` to be a type that is a pointer to a function. Then `func_type func;` declares `func` to be a pointer. Your proposed alternative, `void func(int a, int b);` declares `func` to be a function.

Since you can assign to a pointer, `func = …;` works with the first declaration. Since you cannot assign to a function, `func = …;` does not work with the second declaration.

To declare `func` to be a pointer to a function without using a `typedef`, use `void (*func)(int, int);`.